# make: *** No rule to make target 'Install'. Stop

Tags: raspbian, debian, make, makefile

fairly new to debian and trying to make my first project but I keep running into errors.

Following this tutorial: https://opensource.com/article/19/2/wifi-picture-frame-raspberry-pi

Which leads to this github repo under the "building debian" section: https://github.com/nextcloud/client_theming

I did not follow the install debian section as I already have it installed with raspbian?

I ran the commands below with no error.

```
cmake -D OEM_THEME_DIR=$(realpath ../nextcloudtheme) -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr  ../client
make
```

When I run the next command in the sequence "sudo make install", I receive the following error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
```

Within the client folder, which is where the build was created, there are these files:

```
CMakeCache.txt  CMakeFiles  cmake_install.cmake  CMakeLists.txt  Makefile
```

I have tried cd CMakeFiles and running "sudo make install" within that folder but receive the same error. From my research online, there should be a file within the client folder with the word "install" attached to it and the make command should loop through and find it. I have the install file, however this may not be the correct one? Suggestions are appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you run this command:

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

The `client` folder is a submodule and it looks like the those files are missing.